# Do I need to free BSTRs populated by _Type::get_FullName

Tags: c++, bstr, clr-hosting

I have some code that looks like this:

```
_TypePtr spType = NULL;
. . . // host the CLR and populate that type
{
    BSTR fullName;
    spType->get_FullName(&fullName);
    wprintf(L"Got type %s\n", fullName);
}
```

Do I need to free that bstr? How do I free it [SysFreeString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? If not why?

Comment: @WhozCraig ok how do I free it?

Comment: Use [`SysFreeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909095.aspx). In your case, once finished with it, invoke `SysFreeString(fullName);`

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm doing it from C++ not C# actually.

Comment: Yeah but can't you still call C# functions in C++? Or is this before mscorlib has loaded?

Comment: @Mehrdad If I was doing C++/CLI. I'm instantianting a new CLR instance through COM here in pure unmanaged C++, so I don't have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BSTR` is dynamically allocated by `SysAllocString` (if I recall the name correctly, check it!).

There is a corresponding deallocation function.

Just ***read the documentation***.

---

If you're using the Visual C++ compiler, and don't plan on ever porting the code to other compilers, then you can use the "smart BSTR" class bundled with Visual C++. I can't exactly recall the name. But something like `_bstr_t`. Wait, checking the docs... OK, typing "_bstr" in the index supplied the name, it is `_bstr_t` as I thought! :-)

With use of the "smart" class it handles deallocation for you.

Comment: That was obvious in retrospect. I obviously need to read [Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx)

Comment: `bstr_t` and `ATL::CComBSTR` both are adequate for a smart BSTR class mentioned in this answer.